# How to implement ObjectDecoder(ClassResolver) in Netty 3.2.7

Tags: netty

In netty version 3.2.5 in method

```
public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception { ... }
```

have a decoder defined as follows:

```
pipeline.addLast("decoder", new ObjectDecoder());
```

I have upgraded to Netty version 3.2.7 which has the `ObjectDecoder()` deprecated and it
now requires a `ClassResolver`.
Does anyone have a code example of how to implement the `new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolver)`
in the `getPipeline()` method in version 3.2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the documentation on Netty ClassResolver.

http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/serialization/ClassResolvers.html

Pick the class resolver that best meets your requirements.

I think you maybe able to do something like this:

```
new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.weakCachingConcurrentResolver(null))
```

Comment: Veebs thanks for that solution which works. I now have an exception (which is not related to this solution). The exception occurs when the client sends the message to the server. I have posted the first part of this exception. Does anyone know how this can be resolved. java.io.InvalidClassException: failed to read class descriptor
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)

Comment: Hi, this link may be of help: http://markmail.org/message/4ftws33dxehbzbwd.  Try specifying a ClassLoader.  You may want to mark this question as answered and open another question if you still have problems. Thanks.

Comment: @Veebs: I see it in the code but not in the API (javadocs)... What exactly does this do and mean?